# Can`t unsubscribe and stop work of event hendler on C# in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wQqg.png)

I load some text in textbox, than it disapears, when I write in textbox("Tb" in code), than I can change text with buttons(S by one button, S1 by enother), but after some changes handler ”main_change” eats mostly all the text.

I wanted previous text disapear when I input but not mostly all. What I have triyed I can`t stop handler “main_change”.

More readeble code:

```
   this.Load+= S;
    }
    
    //запускаеться кнопкой 1(button1 на скрине)
    public void S(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        textbox.Text="Привіт";
        textbox.TextChanged+=main_change;
    }
    
    //после ввода удаляет текст и виводит в textbox последнюю букву
    public void main_change(object sender, EventArgs e){
    
        t=textbox.Text;
        textbox.Text=t[t.Length-1].ToString();
        }
        textbox.Select(textbox.Text.Length, 0);
    
        // пробую остановить обработчик
        textbox.TextChanged-=main_change;
    }
    
    void S1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        //запускаеться собитие нажатием кнопки 2(button1 на скрине)
        this.Back.Click+=S;
        
        textbox.Text="Тест";            
        
        ////тоже пробую остановить обработчик
        textbox.TextChanged-=main_change;           
    }
```

Actual version of the code:

```
   int s1 = 0;
   int s2 = 0;
   int s3 = 0;
   int s4 = 0;
   string ss = " ";
  string ss1 = " ";
  string ss2 = " ";
  int t1 = 0;
 string t = " ";

 public MainForm()
 {
InitializeComponent();
    
//добавляю сюда
this.Load += S;
//S(null,null);
 }

 public void S(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
//this.Load -= main_change;
Tb.Text = "Hello";
t1++;
Tb.TextChanged += main_change;
//main_change(null, null);
    
l.Text = t1.ToString();
  }

  public void main_change(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (t1 == 1)
{
    t = Tb.Text;
    Tb.Text = t[t.Length - 1].ToString();
    t1 = 0;
}
Tb.Select(Tb.Text.Length, 0);
    
l.Text = t1.ToString();
return;
//Tb.TextChanged -= main_change;
//this.Back.Click += S;
//Tb.TextChanged -= main_change;
}

  void S1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
this.Back.Click += S;
//if(s2 == 0){
Tb.Text = "Text";
l.Text = t1.ToString();
this.Load += S;
//s2 = 0;
    
Tb.TextChanged -= main_change;
 }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong but you are trying to remove a few characters from the textbox by clicking on the buttons, right ?

Perhaps you can achieve this by setting the focus and the selection at the end of the textbox, and then use the `SendKeys.Send("{BS}")` (since .Net 1.1) each time you want to remove a character. This method works as if you typed the *backspace* key on your keyboard.

Also in the private event handler method `main_changed`, try during debug to spy on the `sender` parameter, so that you will determine which control send the event.
Then by surrounding the body of the event handler with a condition that tests if the sender is one of the two buttons, you can decide to do something or not.

```
public void main_change(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(sender is Button && 
        ((Button)sender).Name == "button1" || ((Button)sender).Name == "button2" )
    {
        // Do something here.
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something else here.
    }
}
```

Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=windowsdesktop-6.0